# Cocoa NSTextContainer: How to maintain whitespace after gap?

Tags: cocoa, nstextcontainer

I am creating a gap in text by overriding NSTextContainer's "lineFragmentRectForProposedRect" and returning a remainingRect.

This works overall, but it is undesirable to me that the "remainingRect" portion of the text container hides whitespace at the beginning of the rect. Anybody know a means of stopping this behaviour?

For example:
"Hello         World!" as the literal text when separated by a gap beginning anywhere between "Hello" and "World!", then the right side of the gap will have no space before "World!", such that, let's say, if the gap was the width of a character and begins right after "Hello", then the result would look like "Hello World!".